# How to make json with infinite parent child category from database

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sqlite, object

I have an SQLite database table

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
|  id    |      Cat_Name      |     Parent_ID       |
|---------------------------------------------------+
|  1     |     Asset          |       NULL          |
+---------------------------------------------------+
|  2     |     Bank           |        1            |
+---------------------------------------------------+
|  3     |     Cash           |        1            |
+---------------------------------------------------+
|  4     |     Petty Cash     |        3            |
+---------------------------------------------------+
|  5     |     ABC Bank       |        2            |
+---------------------------------------------------+
|  6     |  Dollar Account    |        2            |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

i can fetch the data as below

```
[{ id: 1, Category_Name: "Asset", Parent_ID: 0},
 { id: 2, Category_Name: "Bank", Parent_ID: 1},
{ id: 3, Category_Name: "Cash", Parent_ID: 1},
{ id: 4, Category_Name: "Petty_Cash", Parent_ID: 3},
{ id: 5, Category_Name: "ABC_Bank", Parent_ID: 2},
{ id: 6, Category_Name: "Dollar_Account", Parent_ID: 2}]
```

In this table, category and subcategory created by the user, we can't assume how many parent and child categories will be in the table

Now I want pass the data as a nested javascript object to the front end

example

```
{Asset: {Bank: {ABC Bank: 5}, {Dollar Account: 6}
         },
         {Cash:{PettyCash: 4}, if any...}
}
```

Could anybody can help to get this result in the best way...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you change the design of the output object. I think the array approach would be better for the frontend.

```js
const rawData = [
  { id: 1, Category_Name: "Asset", Parent_ID: 0},
  { id: 2, Category_Name: "Bank", Parent_ID: 1},
  { id: 3, Category_Name: "Cash", Parent_ID: 1},
  { id: 4, Category_Name: "Petty Cash", Parent_ID: 3},
  { id: 5, Category_Name: "ABC Bank", Parent_ID: 2},
  { id: 6, Category_Name: "Dollar Account", Parent_ID: 2},
  { id: 7, Category_Name: "Another Wallet", Parent_ID: 4},
];

const getParentDeep = (arr, targetId) => arr.find(({ id }) => id === targetId)
    ?? arr.flatMap(({ children }) => getParentDeep(children, targetId))
    .filter(e => e)
    .at(0);

const result = rawData
  .sort(({ Parent_ID: a }, { Parent_ID: b }) => a - b)
  .reduce((acc, { id, Category_Name, Parent_ID }) => {
    const obj = { id, name: Category_Name, children: [] };
    const parentObj = getParentDeep(acc, Parent_ID);
    if (parentObj) parentObj.children.push(obj)
    else acc.push(obj);
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

The result will look like this:

```
[{
  id: 1,
  name: "Asset",
  children: [{
    id: 2,
    name: "Bank",
    children: [{
      id: 5,
      name: "ABC Bank",
      children: []
    }, {
      id: 6,
      name: "Dollar Account",
      children: []
    }]
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: "Cash",
    children: [{
      id: 4,
      name: "Petty Cash",
      children: [{
        id: 7,
        name: "Another Wallet",
        children: []
      }]
    }]
  }]
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Presented below is one possible way to achieve the desired objective. Admittedly, it is not very elegant (& possibly not the most-efficient).

**Code Snippet**

```js
// helper method to recursively-add to object
const recurAdd = (arr, idx, res) => {
  // when "idx" exceeds length of array "arr", 
  // simply return existing result "res" object
  if (idx >= arr.length) return res;
  
  // de-structure to access parent-id & id for current elt
  const { Parent_ID, id } = arr[idx];
  
  if (Parent_ID in res) {
    // parent-id exists at current object, 
    // so, add "id" to same object (mutate)
    res[Parent_ID][id] = {};
    
    // make recursive call for "next" elt in "arr"
    return recurAdd(arr, idx+1, res);
    
  } else {
    // find next-level object where current elt will fit
    const foundIt = Object.values(res).map(obj => recurAdd(arr, idx, obj));
    // NOTE: "obj" is part of "res" and it gets mutated
    
    // if found, make recursive call
    if (foundIt.some(x => x !== false)) return recurAdd(arr, idx+1, res);
  };
  
  // in case parent-id is not found, simply return false
  return false;
};

// helper method to substitute "id" with "category names"
const recurNamify = (obj, myMap) => (
  // reconstruct object from key-value pairs of intermediate result
  Object.fromEntries(
    // generate intermediate result of key-value pairs
    Object.entries(obj)
    .map(([k, v]) => (
      // substitute key (ie, "id") with category-name
      Object.keys(v).length === 0
      ? [myMap[k], k]
      : [myMap[k], recurNamify(v, myMap)]
    ))
    // when "v" is not an empty object, make recursive call
  )
);

// transform the array into nested object
const myTransform = arr => {
  // first transform "Number" to "string" for id and parent-id
  // because JS-object keys are string type
  const myArr = arr.map(ob => ({
    ...ob,
    id: ob.id.toString(),
    Parent_ID: ob.Parent_ID.toString()
  }));
  
  // generate a dictionary/map for "id" to category-name
  const myMap = myArr.reduce(
    (acc, itm) => {
      acc[itm.id] = itm.Category_Name
      return acc;
    },
    {}
  );
  
  // find the index of root (ie, parent id is zero)
  const rIdx = myArr.findIndex(({ Parent_ID }) => Parent_ID === '0');
  
  // obtain the root & mutate "arr" by removing the root
  const [root] = myArr.splice(rIdx, 1);
  
  // use the helper methods to transform
  return recurNamify(recurAdd(myArr, 0, {[root.id]: {}}), myMap);
};

const rawData = [
  { id: 1, Category_Name: "Asset", Parent_ID: 0},
  { id: 2, Category_Name: "Bank", Parent_ID: 1},
  { id: 3, Category_Name: "Cash", Parent_ID: 1},
  { id: 4, Category_Name: "Petty_Cash", Parent_ID: 3},
  { id: 5, Category_Name: "ABC_Bank", Parent_ID: 2},
  { id: 6, Category_Name: "Dollar_Account", Parent_ID: 2}
];

console.log('transformed: ', myTransform(rawData));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

**Explanation**

Inline comments added to the snippet above.

PS: If you'd like to add value to stackoverflow community,

> Please consider reading: [What to do when my question is answered](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)
>  Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Here's another linked list variation, but with bi-directional object references and JSON de-/serialization in acknowledgement of the client/server relationship:

> The Stack Overflow code snippet virtual console doesn't show interactive object relationships like your browser's JS console, so copy and paste this into your JS console to see the relational references in the final linked list value.

```js
/** Conceptually similar to CSV when stringified, but preserves JSON types */
function compact (keysOrMappedKeys, array) {
  const inputKeys = [];
  let outputKeys = [];

  const keysAreMapped = Array.isArray(keysOrMappedKeys[0]);

  if (keysAreMapped) {
    for (const [keyIn, keyOut] of keysOrMappedKeys) {
      inputKeys.push(keyIn);
      outputKeys.push(keyOut);
    }
  }
  else {
    for (const key of keysOrMappedKeys) inputKeys.push(key);
    outputKeys = inputKeys;
  }

  const rows = [];

  for (const obj of array) {
    const row = [];
    for (const key of inputKeys) row.push(obj[key]);
    rows.push(row);
  }

  return [outputKeys, rows];
}

// Not actually needed for this answer:
/** The reverse of the `compact` function */
function expand ([keys, rows]) {
  return rows.map(array => {
    const obj = {};
    for (const [index, key] of keys.entries()) obj[key] = array[index];
    return obj;
  });
}

/** Expects keys in the order `[ownId, parentId, ...others]` */
function createLinkedObjectList ([keys, rows]) {
  const map = new Map(rows.map(row => {
    const obj = {};
    const iter = keys.entries();
    const [ownIdIndex] = iter.next().value;
    const ownId = row[ownIdIndex];
    const [parentIdIndex] = iter.next().value;
    const parentId = row[parentIdIndex];
    for (const [index, key] of iter) obj[key] = row[index];
    return [ownId, {id: ownId, parentId, value: obj}];
  }));

  for (const obj of map.values()) {
    const parent = map.get(obj.parentId);
    if (typeof parent !== 'undefined') {
      obj.parent = parent;
      (parent.children ??= []).push(obj);
    }
    delete obj.parentId;
  }

  return [...map.values()];
}


// Use: On the server:

// From the SQLite db:
const input = [
  { id: 1, Category_Name: "Asset", Parent_ID: 0},
  { id: 2, Category_Name: "Bank", Parent_ID: 1},
  { id: 3, Category_Name: "Cash", Parent_ID: 1},
  { id: 4, Category_Name: "Petty_Cash", Parent_ID: 3},
  { id: 5, Category_Name: "ABC_Bank", Parent_ID: 2},
  { id: 6, Category_Name: "Dollar_Account", Parent_ID: 2},
];

// Optionally, rename the keys when compacting the data structure:
const mappedKeys = [
  ['id', 'id'], // The ID key needs to be first
  ['Parent_ID', 'parent'], // The parent ID key needs to be second
  // The order of the remaining keys is simply preference:
  ['Category_Name', 'name'],
];

const compacted = compact(mappedKeys, input);

/*
Or, just use the original key names:

const keys = [
  'id', // The ID key needs to be first
  'Category_Name', // The parent ID key needs to be second
  // The order of the remaining keys is simply preference:
  'Parent_ID',
];

const compacted = compact(keys, input);
*/

// You can send this JSON string to the client
const json = JSON.stringify(compacted);
console.log(json); // [["id","parent","name"],[[1,0,"Asset"],[2,1,"Bank"],[3,1,"Cash"],[4,3,"Petty_Cash"],[5,2,"ABC_Bank"],[6,2,"Dollar_Account"]]]


// Use: On the client:

/* After receiving the json from the server:

const json = await getDataFromServer();

Expand it into a linked list with bi-directional references
between actual parent and children objects.
This is where the order of the keys matters: */
const list = createLinkedObjectList(compacted);
console.log(list); /* Looks like this:

[
  {
    id: 1,
    value: { name: 'Asset' },
    children: [
      { id: 2, ... },
      { id: 3, ... },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    value: { name: 'Bank' },
    parent: { id: 1, ... },
    children: [
      { id: 5, ... },
      { id: 6, ... },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    value: { name: 'Cash' },
    parent: { id: 1, ... },
    children: [
      { id: 4, ... },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    value: { name: 'Petty_Cash' },
    parent: { id: 3, ... },
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    value: { name: 'ABC_Bank' },
    parent: { id: 2, ... },
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    value: { name: 'Dollar_Account' },
    parent: { id: 2, ... },
  },
]

*/
```